# Is the BroadcastReceiver.onReceive called exactly once per sms?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, pdu

I have a BroadcastReceiver listenting for android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED. I am going to intercept some SMS, so I will abortBroadcast(), but not for all SMS.

But when I extract the SMS from the intent, I guess I can get MORE than one SMS?

```
Object[] messages = (Object[]) intent.getSerializableExtra("pdus");
```

messages is an Object[], does it mean it could be several SMS? or I can safely assume it will always be one SMS.

My problem is that if I receive several SMS and I need to intercept only one, I cannot just operate correctly, cause if I abortBroadcast() the user will loose some legit SMS and if I don't he will get some SMS he should not.

I am on Android 2.2

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it myself but according to the links below "once per sms" rule is not correct. Particularly, onReceive is called with messages.length > 1 in the case of multipart messages.

I think these links would be helpful:

- [Android - receiving long SMS (multipart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306020/android-receiving-long-sms-multipart)
- [gTalkSMS source code](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/gtalksms/receivers/SmsReceiver.java)