# Receive multipart Message

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I'm newbie in Android, I make android Sms Aplication,
It's not error but it can't receive long sms (more than 160 characters),
This is my code for SMSReceiver, where is my wrong code? please help me..

```
package com.tugas_akhir;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import model.SMS;
import com.niusounds.sqlite.SQLiteDAO;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public SQLiteDAO dao;
public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent)
{
Toast.makeText(paramContext, "SMS diterima", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat localSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm, dd MMM yyyy");
    dao = SQLiteDAO.getInstance(paramContext, new Class[] { SMS.class });
    Bundle localBundle = paramIntent.getExtras();
   String str = "";
(SmsMessage[]) = null;
Object[] arrayOfObject = null;
SmsMessage[] arrayOfSmsMessage = null;
if (localBundle != null)
{
  arrayOfObject = (Object[])localBundle.get("pdus");
  arrayOfSmsMessage = new SmsMessage[arrayOfObject.length];
}
for (int i = 0; ; i++)
{
    if (i >= arrayOfSmsMessage.length)

  {
    Toast.makeText(paramContext, "TERIMA SMS : " + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
  }
//insert into table
  arrayOfSmsMessage[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])arrayOfObject[i]);
  SMS localSMS = new SMS();
  str = arrayOfSmsMessage[i].getMessageBody().toString();
  localSMS.setNoHp(arrayOfSmsMessage[i].getOriginatingAddress().toString());
  localSMS.setPesan(arrayOfSmsMessage[i].getMessageBody().toString());
  localSMS.setTime(localSimpleDateFormat.format(localCalendar.getTime()));

  dao.insert(localSMS);
  }
  }
  }
```

help me..

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5017830/2741980)! You should be able to get

Comment: I was try that code, but It's did not work

Answer (score -1):

Try this class for Receiving Message

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
            }
            String replyPhone = msgs[0].getOriginatingAddress();
            String request = msgs[0].getMessageBody().toString();
            //---display the new SMS message---
            //  Toast.makeText(context, str + "    " + replyPhone + "\n" + request, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(1000);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add some more info beside just copying some code from internet?