# Is there any possibility to get userDataHeader from android SmsMessage?

Tags: android, sms

Interested in getting few fields (msgCount, refNumber and seqNumber) from userDataHeader in android SmsMessage object. Does anyone know if it's possible?

[object structure tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTQ6U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Those fields are about three levels deep in private/hidden classes. You can get them with reflection, but do you really need to? `msgCount` will be equal to the length of the PDU array. The PDUs are ordered, so figuring `seqNumber` for each is trivial. And I can't think of any reason you'd need `refNumber`, which is used by the internals and the backend to track submission success/failure and to issue status reports.

In any case, the following is a reflective method you can use to confirm this. Note that these values are only relevant to multipart messages. The data header will be null for single-part messages.

```
private void listMessageConcatRef(SmsMessage msg) {
    try {
        Field msgBaseField = SmsMessage.class.getDeclaredField("mWrappedSmsMessage"); 
        Object msgBase = msgBaseField.get(msg);

        Class<?> msgBaseCls = Class.forName(
            "com.android.internal.telephony.SmsMessageBase");
        Field dataHeaderField = msgBaseCls.getDeclaredField("mUserDataHeader");
        dataHeaderField.setAccessible(true);
        Object dataHeader = dataHeaderField.get(msgBase);

        if (dataHeader == null) {
            Log.d("SmsMessage", "null data header");
            return;
        }

        Class<?> headerCls = Class.forName(
            "com.android.internal.telephony.SmsHeader");
        Field concatRefField = headerCls.getDeclaredField("concatRef");
        Object concatRef = concatRefField.get(dataHeader);

        Class<?> concatRefCls = Class.forName(
            "com.android.internal.telephony.SmsHeader$ConcatRef");
        Field msgCountField = concatRefCls.getDeclaredField("msgCount");
        Field refNumberField = concatRefCls.getDeclaredField("refNumber");
        Field seqNumberField = concatRefCls.getDeclaredField("seqNumber");
        Field isEightBitsField = concatRefCls.getDeclaredField("isEightBits");

        int msgCount = msgCountField.get(concatRef);
        int refNumber = refNumberField.get(concatRef);
        int seqNumber = seqNumberField.get(concatRef);
        boolean isEightBits = isEightBitsField.get(concatRef);

        Log.d("ConcatRef", "msgCount = " + msgCount);
        Log.d("ConcatRef", "refNumber = " + refNumber);
        Log.d("ConcatRef", "seqNumber = " + seqNumber);
        Log.d("ConcatRef", "isEightBits = " + isEightBits);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. It seems if it's possible only by reflection then I really don't need these fields.
I would like to add extra checkings (and if it's required extra actions) for multipart messages in order to garantee that i received all parts and in correct order. It's becouse i have read in several articles, that PDU's might not be delivered in sequence (for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306020/android-receiving-long-sms-multipart))

Comment: It sounds like whoever wrote that question didn't implement their app correctly. I've never received parts of a multipart message out of order. I don't even think it's possible, unless something went really, really wrong in transmission, or somehow a device's system is corrupted. That's what `seqNumber` is for, and the internals handle sorting the parts before they're delivered to your `BroadcastReceiver`. You can use the posted method to run tests for that, if you like.

Comment: Is't possible to receive few messages from different senders or different messages from one sender (not parts) in one intent? For example if I turn on my phone?

Comment: Nope, not really, unless, again, something went really wrong somewhere.

Comment: Incomplete concatenated messages are stored in the raw table until all parts arrive, after which they will be delivered in a single intent. There is a tiny risk that a concatenated message contains segments from different messages (see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/f39de086fddea9e9f6b8c56b04d8dd38a84237db/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/InboundSmsHandler.java#602), if both messages are concatenated messages from the same sender, with the same segment count and refnumber. In a very poor network it could happen but it's not very likely..

Comment: Yes, if multiple, sequential multipart messages have the same `refNumber`, that would be something going wrong. In any case, it's not something the receiving client can easily deduce, or do anything about, really.